# Update UnitAmount of Stripe Checkout Price

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments, e-commerce

I'm using Stripe Checkout and would like to update the UnitAmount of a Price.

However, the Update Price API doesn't allow UnitPrice. This is the code from Stripe's API Documentation:

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "{MY_API_KEY}";

var options = new PriceUpdateOptions
{
    Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "order_id", "6735" },
    },
};
var service = new PriceService();
service.Update("gold", options);
```

And these are the properties in PriceUpdateOptions:

```
[JsonProperty("active")]
public bool? Active { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("lookup_key")]
public string LookupKey { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("metadata")]
public Dictionary<string, string> Metadata { get; set; }
public string Nickname { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("recurring")]
public PriceRecurringOptions Recurring { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("transfer_lookup_key")]
public bool? TransferLookupKey { get; set; }
```

Looking at the properties, UnitAmount doesn't seem to be editable once Price has been created.

I would like to do something like:

```
public void UpdateStripePrice(Product updatedProductResponse, ProductViewModel updatedProduct)
{
    StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "{MY_API_KEY}";

    var options = new PriceUpdateOptions
    {
        Product = updatedProductResponse.Id,
        UnitAmount = (long)updatedProduct.Price * 100,
    };

    var service = new PriceService();
    service.Update(updatedProduct.StripePriceId, options);
}
```

I'm also unable to find a way of removing a Price, and "updating" it by recreating it.

Comment: Prices can't be deleted and updating only allows the  `metadata`, `nickname`, and `active` fields to be updated so the approach is rather to archive the Price and create a new one if required. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for you reply! However, I can't find any information on how to archive a Price either. Would you mind please explaining what this means?

Comment: I just realized that's something you can do from the Stripe Dashboard. Thanks!

Comment: Set `active` to false to archive.

Comment: @albinioni You can change the unit_amount of the price only if it is not used yet.